# Кеширование реляционых запросов YII

Tags: кэширование, yii, php

Здравствуйте. Скажите как правильней кешировать реляционые и обычные запросы к базе?

К базе идут запросы с Контроллера и реляционные с Вида, не могу понять как организовать кеширование.

Comment:  1. Запросы с "Вида" (полагаю, это из представения (view)) - за это уже можно руки отрубать.
 2. Что значит обычные запросы и реляционные?
 3. Какой кеш вы используете?



Comment: вы пользовались реляционными запросами в yii? с вида они обращаются не как SQL запрос а как к методу. обычный файловый кеш, реляционные запросы используются для таблиц между которыми установлена связь.

Answer (score 1):

Берешь запрос, и кешируешь его. можно ведь кешировать запросы, а можно кешировать данные полученные.

Не вижу сложности в кешировании запросов. в документации ведь с примерами есть.

Comment: В вашем предложение я так же не вижу ничего сложного, но, не удобно это в каждом виде и в контроллере кешировать. Мне интереснее Глобальное решение, для вьюх и контроллеров, теорию хотя бы.

Comment: кешировать данные модели в контроллере или вьюхе??? Это извращения!

Если кешировать запросы то в модели, данные тоже в модели.

Куски вывода, ну тут можно поизвращаться в контроллере.

Что нужно-то сделать? Вопрос поставлен крайне узко!

Comment: У меня к примеру на страничке 5-6 запросов, все данные я хочу поместить в один Кеш Файл, но в YII все запросы идут с разных моделей, получается 1 запрос хронится в одном кеш файле(это если кешировать в моделях), не думаю что в этом случаи ускориться сайт

Comment: Да хоть 100 запросов на странице. Скорость быдет выше.

У меня на странице от 10-35 запросов, скорость в 40раз больше при кешировании, нежели постоянно терзать БД.